# USB WiFi adapter keeps dropping connection?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, wpa

I have a headless Fedora Linux box that I'm trying to get an Alfa AWUS036H USB wireless adapter to work with. I'm trying to connect to my own wireless network (an Actiontec router supplied by my ISP). The wireless signal seems strong (taskbar widget shows it 4/5 bars full).

Using a VNC desktop session, after entering the WPA password, it works for a while, and then after a few minutes, the connection drops and I can see in my desktop the networking indicator go back to the "spinning" icon, and it eventually pops up an authentication dialog to re-enter the WPA password, but re-entering it doesn't work.

Taking a look at the `dmesg` log, I see:

```
[311950.773254] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[311952.761985] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[311997.648652] wlan0: authenticate with 10:5f:06:e2:96:ed
[311997.721638] wlan0: send auth to 10:5f:06:e2:96:ed (try 1/3)
[311997.724327] wlan0: authenticated
[311997.724575] rtl8187 1-2:1.0: wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported
[311997.762042] wlan0: associate with 10:5f:06:e2:96:ed (try 1/3)
[311997.765207] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 10:5f:06:e2:96:ed (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=10)
[311997.765936] wlan0: associated
[311997.765980] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[312122.930027] ieee80211 phy10: wlan0: No probe response from AP 10:5f:06:e2:96:ed after 500ms, disconnecting.
[312122.949129] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[312122.951792] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[312122.951797] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[312122.951800] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[312122.951803] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[312122.951805] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[312122.951807] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[312122.951810] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[312122.951836] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[312122.954992] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
[312122.954998] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[312122.955048] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[312122.955051] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 1700 mBm)
[312122.955054] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[312122.955056] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5600000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[312122.955058] cfg80211:   (5650000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[312122.955060] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 3000 mBm)
[312124.123657] wlan0: authenticate with 10:5f:06:e2:96:ed
[312124.196672] wlan0: send auth to 10:5f:06:e2:96:ed (try 1/3)
[312124.397018] wlan0: send auth to 10:5f:06:e2:96:ed (try 2/3)
[312124.598019] wlan0: send auth to 10:5f:06:e2:96:ed (try 3/3)
[312124.799018] wlan0: authentication with 10:5f:06:e2:96:ed timed out
```

You can see in the first five lines, the `wlan0` interface does successfully authenticate to the router. But then a little while later, there's "No probe response from AP", and it seems to try and set up its own wireless network, looking for a WiFi channel that's open? And then it tries to re-authenticate to the router, and fails, where it succeeded just a few minutes ago.

From these logs, is it the IPv6 broadcast that's throwing my adapter off? Or is it the "disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported"?

The "no probe response" is only waiting 500ms for a response from the server. Can that be increased in some configuration somewhere (is my router just being slow to respond)?

**EDIT:** More detail on the router side:
It's an Actiontec T2200H running firmware TDST2200H-31.126L.04. One odd thing I noticed looking at the router's web interface is it's claiming its MAC address is 10:5F:06:E2:96:EC. That's one digit off from what's in the logs on the Linux client side (logs show that the final grouping should be "ED", not "EC")? Wireless security is set to WPA/WPA2-TKIP+AES. WWM is enabled and WWM Power saving disabled.

Other computers in the house, using PCI wireless cards, can connect with no issue. Is this just because the Alfa USB adapter cannot handle the WMM or IPv6 commands?

Comment: What exact model and hardware revision of wireless router do you have? Is WMM/QoS enabled on it? Is WPA2-PSK (a.k.a. WPA2 Personal) enabled on it?

Comment: Added more detail above; Actiontec T2200H, yes WMM is enabled, with WPA/WPA2 security enabled.